# Dynamically hiding elements in a  list without the hidden elements occupying empty space on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to hide elements based on what a user does. if he presses "a only", I can say something like

```
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("b").length;i++){
      document.getElementsByClassName("b")[i].style.visibility="hidden";
 }
```

but this will leave empty spaces between elements in the list (the invisible elements still occupy space), which looks bad, is there a better way this can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try style.display="none"

Using visibilty="hidden", the elements will still take up their calculated space on the page.

You may also consider using jQUery.  It makes tasks like these incredibly simple.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. You are setting the `visibility` CSS property to `hidden`. This stops the element from being displayed, but it still occupies space.

You want to set the `display` property to be `none`. This removes it from being displayed, *and* stops it occupying space - effectively removing it from the document, at least as far as displaying it is concerned.

```
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("b").length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("b")[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: none` instead of `visiblity: hidden`.  The `visibility` property only hides the element; the `display` property actually removes the element from the layout.

Answer (score 0):

For visibility:hidden, the javascript parser will parse the elements css properties and hides, it actually exist on dom, but user cannot see.
For display: none, when javascript parser finds the element with display, it just ignore the element and it move ahead. So you have to user display: none;